# Can someone help me with find elements in RPAFramework

Tags: python, selenium, rpa

I'm trying to iterate over a table row searching by the xpath of element "tr". But when I'll try find the elements "td" to iterate over them and get the text I get the error "invalid locator". It's just a test, but can someone help me with this? Below is the code:

```
from RPA.Browser.Selenium import Selenium

lib = Selenium()

lib.open_available_browser("https://ge.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/")
lib.wait_until_element_is_visible('xpath://*[@id="classificacao__wrapper"]/article/section[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr')
trs = lib.find_elements('xpath://*[@id="classificacao__wrapper"]/article/section[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr')

for tr in trs:
    td = tr.find_elements('tag:td')
    print(td)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. The documentation to python of RPAFramework it's very confusing and searching inside module "webelement" I discovered that the method "find_elements" don't work. I've needed to replace by "find_elements_by_tag_name". This is the code now:

```
from RPA.Browser.Selenium import Selenium

lib = Selenium()

lib.open_available_browser("https://ge.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/")
lib.wait_until_element_is_visible('xpath://*[@id="classificacao__wrapper"]/article/section[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr')
trs = lib.find_elements('xpath://*[@id="classificacao__wrapper"]/article/section[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr')

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for td in tds:
        print(td.text)
```